# MongoDB - Java - Retrieve elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm very new to MongoDB, and I'm using it along with the Java driver. I have this document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5598734f96de4e47f61f250c"),

    "restaurant_name" : ["restaurant_1"],

    "menu" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B", 
        "C", 
        "D", 
        "E", 
        "F"
    ]
}
```

According to this example I want to put all the element of menu in an array (to do something with the elmements of the array) and display them like:

```
Name: restaurant_1

Menu: A B C D E F
```

I want to do something with the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class QueryDB {
    static MongoClient clientMongo;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        getMenu("restaurant_1");

    }

    private static void getMenu(String restaurant) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            clientMongo = new MongoClient();
            DB db = clientMongo.getDB("**DATABASE NAME**");
            DBCollection collectionMongo = db.getCollection("**COLLECTION NAME**");
            DBCursor cursor = collectionMongo.find(new BasicDBObject("menu",
                    restaurant));
            if (cursor.count() == 0)
                System.out.println("No Menu found");
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next().get("menu"));
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Could not connect to Database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But the menu is displayed with special characters ([,",]).  I want to display them without special characters and save the different elements of menu in an array.

Comment: I tried to use System.out.println(cursor.next().get("restaurant_name")); and BasicDBList e = (BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("menu"); but the result of the query is reduced.